# Hibernate/DB2 getting unknown column error 4460

Tags: hibernate, orm, db2

I am trying to map an entity to an existing table for read-only purposes. The account I am using only has SELECT privileges.

The column I am mapping my @ID to is already populated. My entity looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE", schema="MYSCHEMA")
public class PaymentsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ssn", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long ssn;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(name = "business_date")
    private Date businessDate;

    @Column(name = "receiver")
    private String receiver;

    @Column(name = "sender")
    private String sender;

    // getters and setters

}
```

My repository looks like this

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface PaymentsRepository extends JpaRepository<PaymentsEntity, BigInteger> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT sender, receiver, amount, business_date FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE WHERE business_date = ?1 ORDER BY Amount ASC",
        nativeQuery = true)
    public List<PaymentsEntity> findByBusinessDate(Date businessDate);

}
```

When I invoke the findByBusinessDate method, I get the following error

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10150][10300][4.19.49] Invalid parameter: Unknown column name ssn. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null
```

If I change the type of the ssn field to BigInteger, I get the following error

```
 org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [ssn] in table [PFA.PAYMENTS]; found [bigint (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [decimal(19,2) (Types#NUMERIC)]
```

So, the column isn't really unknown and I am getting an unhelpful error message.

I have tried using the useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=2 connection parameter, but it doesn't change anything.

I am using Hibernate 5.4.6.FINAL and the IBM DB2 driver is version 4.19.49. The DB2 database is version 10.5 running on AIX.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first exception you get is related to missing `ssn` in your sql projection. The correct query should be `SELECT ssn, sender, receiver, amount, business_date...` The second exception's cause looks entirely different. Probably, GenerationType.IDENTITY requires the property type to be Long.